# ship - which or who

Tags: grammar

As I know, we use she for ship instead of it.

How we make description for ship?

"The ship which left the harbour at..." 
or
"The ship who left the harbour at..."

I have been told it is with which, but I found these novels:

- [The Ship Who Sang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang)
- [The Ship Who Searched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Searched)

Also I made two simple searches in Google for exact matches. There results are:

- "ship who" - 384 000 matches
- "ship which" - 495 000 matches

So which is the correct? Are both cases possible?

Comment: Well, I would say "The ship which *left* the harbor..."

Comment: The two examples you give are both part of the same [SF series](http://www.pern.nl/moremac/ship.html) which also includes titles like _The City Who Fought_. A quick read indicates it's about a human brain implanted in a spaceship. Because of that, the (space)ship becomes (almost) human, which the author shows by using _who_ instead of _which_. Are both cases possible? Yes, if you are an established SCiFi author _and you know what you are doing with the language_. Otherwise, just use _which_ like everybody else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the misconception that this is a grammatical idiosyncrasy rather than a plot device.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This site is used by many non-native people. These grammatical exceptions are not trivial for many of them. (normally "she" needs "who") If this is easy for you, I suppose similar exceptions in Russian, French. German or Japanese (for e.g.) will be not obvious for you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth According Google, this "plot device" is used as often as the original phrase.

Comment: @joro There is a sister site (ELL) that was set up specifically for those whose English is not yet of a high enough standard to match the ELU template. I wouldn't presume to post on a site equivalent to ELU aimed at Russian, French. German or Japanese linguists. I've no problems with learners using ELU, but when they try to change its ethos, I feel they're being unfair. // The question of ascribing gender to ships, locomotives ... in English has been covered before. However, using 'the ship / locomotive _who_' is non-idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, it's my mistake. This site description is "Q&A for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts" and I do not fall into any of these groups. I registered into this site by just reading the short name. And the short name seems very inaccurate for its description. Feel free to close the question. Regards

Comment: @joro You're very welcome here; we're by no means a secret society. But there are a lot of people (unlike yourself, who seem very reasonable) who demand ELU change its aims to suit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "she" to describe ships is a poetic tradition.  It doesn't **make them into women**.  They're still objects.  Use "which" or "that".

The two novels you mention are **artistic creations** - I could write a book called "The rock who sang" and that wouldn't change the meaning of "rock" as far as the English language was concerned.

As for your google search, most of the top results for "ship who" (with quotes) refer to the novel you mentioned already, so we can discount them as evidence for anything relevant to the actual language itself.  If I do a search for

```
"ship who" - "the ship who sang"
```

ie, removing results with "the ship who sang" in them it goes down to 34,000.

Incidentally, searching for "ship that" gave 6.5 million results.

At the best of times, comparing the number of google search results is a very unreliable way of establishing the correctness of anything.  More useful is google ngrams, which looks at the content of books, which are a more reliable way to view the idiomatic use of words.  Eg

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The ship which leaved the harbour at..." or "The ship who leaved the harbour at..." It appears, you meant LEFT and not LEAVED.

[leaved
1
adj having leaves or leaves as specified; often used in combination
“four- leaved clover”
Synonyms:
leafed
leafy
having or covered with leaves-https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/leaved ] Coming to the answer of your query,it looks where ship was described as WHO, it was a metaphoric use by a writer or poet. People attached to ship emotionally are known to regard her as a beloved, a mother or even a goddess. For lesser mortals probably WHICH shall be okay.

Comment: If a sailor is “attached to ship emotionally and regard it/she as a beloved, a mother or even a goddess” he could call it “her”. So could the sailor use “who” in this case? Your reply has much words and has no answer.

Comment: "People attached to ship emotionally" - no, not only. Using she for ships is optional, without need of emotional connection. Or wikipedia is wrong.